# onItemSelected() not called, but same implementation working in other file

Tags: android, spinner

The spinner is implemented correctly but the item selection is not working. But similar implementation is working in other file. Actually i'm trying to fetch the item selected from the spinner and store it on the firebase, but onItemSelected() is not being called as a result of which no data is being sent to the firebase.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_create_faculty_profile);
    getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_HIDDEN);

    Spinner createProfileFacultyDepartmentSpinner = findViewById(R.id.create_profile_faculty_department_spinner);
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> createProfileFacultyDepartmentAdapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
            R.array.department_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);

    createProfileFacultyDepartmentAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    createProfileFacultyDepartmentSpinner.setAdapter(createProfileFacultyDepartmentAdapter);

    /* retrieving the student's authenticated phone no. from the authentication activity
     *  and setting it to the textview for database purpose other variable's identification.
     */

    final TextView createProfileFacultyPhoneTextView = findViewById(R.id.create_profile_faculty_phone_textview);
    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    if(mAuth != null){
        createProfileFacultyPhoneTextView.setText(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getPhoneNumber());
    }
    createProfileFacultyNameEditText = findViewById(R.id.create_profile_faculty_name_edittext);
    createProfileFacultyPasswordEditText = findViewById(R.id.create_profile_faculty_password_edittext);
    createProfileFacultyCreateButton = findViewById(R.id.create_profile_faculty_create_button);

    /* Initialize Firebase instance */

    final FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    final DatabaseReference faculty_table = database.getReference("FACULTY");

    createProfileFacultyCreateButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            final ProgressDialog mDialog = new ProgressDialog(CreateFacultyProfile.this);
            mDialog.setMessage("Creating your profile...");
            mDialog.show();

            faculty_table.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    if(dataSnapshot.child(createProfileFacultyPhoneTextView.getText().toString()).exists()){
                        mDialog.dismiss();
                        Toast.makeText(CreateFacultyProfile.this, "Already Registered.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    } else {
                        FACULTY faculty = new FACULTY(createProfileFacultyNameEditText.getText().toString(),
                                                      createProfileFacultyDepartment,
                                                      createProfileFacultyPasswordEditText.getText().toString());
                        faculty_table.child(createProfileFacultyPhoneTextView.getText().toString()).setValue(faculty);
                        Toast.makeText(CreateFacultyProfile.this, "Welcome On Board :)", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                           int pos, long id) {
    // An item was selected. You can retrieve the selected item using
    // parent.getItemAtPosition(pos)
    Spinner createProfileFacultyDepartmentSpinner = findViewById(R.id.create_profile_faculty_department_spinner);
    if(pos == 0){
        TextView errorText = (TextView)createProfileFacultyDepartmentSpinner.getSelectedView();
        errorText.setError("");
        errorText.setTextColor(Color.RED);
    } else {
        createProfileFacultyDepartment = String.valueOf(parent.getItemAtPosition(pos));
    }
}

@Override
public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
    // Another interface callback
}
}
```

Comment: You never call `setOnItemSelectedListener()` on the `Spinner`.

Comment: @AnuraagBaishya Please be careful with your edits. You removed too much there.

Comment: Oh. My bad. Will take care. Thanks for letting me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have forgotten to set `setOnItemSelectedListener(this)` on the spinner.

Comment: Thanks @parekhkruti26 ,